# Dplyr & purrr with dynamic column names, select & copy by group

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I've got the following code where I need to grab column names from a variable then perform an operation selectively on rows, using the specified column in that operation.  Here is my simple example, creating column `res` to match column `targe`t:

```
library(tidyverse)

tst <- tibble(grp = c("a","a","b","b","c","c"), a = rep(2,6), b = rep(4,6), 
              c = rep(8,6), target = c(2,2,4,4,8,8), res = rep(0,6))

# create list of columns to iterate over
lst <-  unique(tst$grp)

# loop over each column, creating a dummy column with 
# the copied value in the matching rows, zeroes elsewhere
for(g in lst) {

  tst <- tst %>% 
    mutate(!!paste("res", g, sep="_") := ifelse(grp == g, !!rlang::sym(g),0)) %>% 
    select(!!paste("res", g, sep="_")) %>% 
    cbind(tst)
}

# combine the dummy columns by rowSum
res <- tst %>% select(starts_with("res_")) %>% mutate(res = rowSums(.)) %>% 
select(res)

# tidy up the output, result matches the target
tst <- tst %>% select(grp, a, b, c, target) %>% cbind(res)

tst

  grp a b c target res
1   a 2 4 8      2   2
2   a 2 4 8      2   2
3   b 2 4 8      4   4
4   b 2 4 8      4   4
5   c 2 4 8      8   8
6   c 2 4 8      8   8
```

I've taken an iterative approach, looping through the unique variables in the `grp` column, creating temporary columns then `rowSum()`ing these to get the final result.  Clunky, but got there in the end.

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it with one of the `map` family from `purrr`.  Can someone show me how I can do this without the loop using `purrr`?  I really struggled to get the dynamic column name bit working using this approach. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `imap`, which iterates over column values and their names. The column values are the values of `grp`, the names is just the sequence `1,...,6`.

In addition, you have to provide the data frame itself as an additional argument (`df=` to `imap`, which it forwards to it's function argument. In total:

```
tst %>% 
  mutate(res = purrr::imap_dbl(grp, df = ., 
    .f = function(g, i, df) df[i,g][[1]] # [[1]] turns the result from tibble into a double
  ))
```

---

Edit: I timed this solution with a larger table:

```
tst <- tst[sample(nrow(tst), 50000, TRUE),]
```

and it takes about 50s.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was after

Comment: @ScottSimpson If you have a large (>10000 rows) table, you might want to check out the [pure R solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50697373/3082472) which is faster by a factor of 5000.

Answer (score 1):

Something that does not require you to write a loop

```
library(tidyverse)

tst <- tibble(grp = c("a","a","b","b","c","c"), a = rep(2,6), b = rep(4,6), 
              c = rep(8,6), target = c(2,2,4,4,8,8), res = rep(0,6))

tst %>% 
  mutate(res = 
           case_when(
             grp == "a" ~ a,
             grp == "b" ~ b,
             grp == "c" ~ c
           ))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  grp       a     b     c target   res
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         2     4     8      2     2
2 a         2     4     8      2     2
3 b         2     4     8      4     4
4 b         2     4     8      4     4
5 c         2     4     8      8     8
6 c         2     4     8      8     8
```

Note: instead of `~ a` you can use your own formula if needed.
For more help see `?case_when`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
tst %>% 
  mutate(res = sapply(seq(nrow(tst)), function(x) tst[x,as.character(tst$grp[x])]))


# A tibble: 6 x 6
    grp     a     b     c target   res
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     2     4     8      2     2
2     a     2     4     8      2     2
3     b     2     4     8      4     4
4     b     2     4     8      4     4
5     c     2     4     8      8     8
6     c     2     4     8      8     8
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is a base R solution, which is also not longer:

```
# Save all source columns in a matrix. This enables indexing by another matrix
x <- as.matrix(tst[, unique(tst$grp)])
# Matrix of (row, column) pairs to extract from x
i <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(tst)), match(tst$grp, colnames(x)))
tst$res <- x[i]
```

---

Edit: Elapsed time for a larger table:

```
tst <- tst[sample(nrow(tst), 50000, TRUE), ]
```

0.008s -- 0.015s